# VB.Net Add to Existing Zip File

Tags: vb.net, zip, ionic-zip

So I have a Zip file that is like the following: \server\test\test\Alphabet.zip

And the contents of the zip file are 3 text files:  
Alphabet.zip  
    -A.txt  
    -B.txt  
    -C.txt

Now in the same path, I have 3 more text files and few more files.  
\server\test\test\D.txt  
\server\test\test\E.txt  
\server\test\test\F.txt  
\server\test\test\image.jpg  
\server\test\test\image2.jpg

I want to add the 3 text files to the existing zip using DotNetZip. 
As I have to add hundreds of files, adding them file by file takes a lot of time. Getting a list and adding the list is a lot faster.
But the problem I have is when I add the list of files to the zip, the folders of the directory are also created inside the zip as well and the 3 txt files are in the folder.
I got like

Alphabet.zip  
    -A.txt  
    -B.txt  
    -C.txt  
    -\server\  
             \test\  
                  \test\  
                       -D.txt  
                       -E.txt  
                       -F.txt

What I want is

Alphabet.zip  
    -A.txt  
    -B.txt  
    -C.txt  
    -D.txt  
    -E.txt  
    -F.txt

I used dotnetzip and the code is as follows

```
Dim path = \\server\test\test\
Dim txtfiles as New List(Of String)

Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
Dim filelist as IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles(di)

for each file in filelist
     If file.Extension = "*.txt" Then
     txtfiles.Add(file.FullName)
End If

Using zip As Ionic.Zip.ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(\\server\test\test\Alphabet.zip)
    zip.AddFiles(txtfiles)
    zip.Save()
End Using
```

Comment: You should have a look through the documentation; maybe the [AddFiles Method (fileNames, directoryPathInArchive)](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/007fac8a-e77e-f558-41e4-572d47946c33.htm) is what you're looking for. "Adds a set of files to the ZipFile, using the specified directory path in the archive.... Passing the empty string ("") will insert the item at the root path within the archive."

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I added the “” when adding the list if files to the zip file.

```
zip.AddFiles(txtfiles, “”)
```